# joint and separate maximimization / minimization

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Suppose we are given a function $f(x,y):\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}$ of two variables. I know that the following is true

$$\inf_x\inf_yf(x,y) = \inf_y\inf_xf(x,y)=\inf_{x,y}f(x,y) $$
where the infimum is taken over subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$. Can we also deduce the same for maximization / supremum, i.e.

$$\inf_x\sup_yf(x,y) = \sup_y\sup_xf(x,y)=\sup_{x,y}f(x,y) $$

The reason why I'm asking, I would like to write a $\sup_x\sup_y f(x,y)$ as an $\inf$ problem.

Comment: There seems to be an $\inf$ typo...

Comment: Well clearly $\sup_x \sup_y f(x, y) = -\inf_x -\sup_y f(x, y) = -\inf_x \inf_y - f(x, y)$ since $\sup g = - \inf -g$ for any function $g$...